Pagination in the GetMessages action from the Microsoft Teams connector
My goal is to fetch all the messages created less than 48 hours ago from a specific Teams Channel and process them in bulk.
I assumed the GetMessages action was a good fit for this problem, it fetches messages from a specified Teams Channel.
minimal reproducible example
However I noticed that I don't receive all messages from the channel (only the latest 20). On busy days there might be more than 20 messages that were created less than 48 hours ago.
There seems to be some kind of "Pagination" setting, but I don't understand how to use that in Power Automate in order to get more messages.
I don't think it is a problem if I receive more messages than the ones created less than 48 hours ago since I can filter them on creation date in the next action.
So to sum things up:

How does Pagination work for GetMessages?
Is my strategy using Pagination reasonable for reaching my goal?


You can turn on pagination in the HTTP action settings and set the limit as shown below: https://i.sstatic.net/TLwOgKJj.png

You can turn on pagination in the HTTP action settings and set the limit as shown below:

